# Jenkins init.groovy.d script to set a build description

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a script in the init.groovy.d/ directory which runs when Jenkins starts. I want to look for some job runs and stop them.

All seems to be working fine except when I enable matrix security (which we need to use on our production system).

The relevant groovy code is:

```
def busyExecutors = Jenkins.instance.computers.collect { 
    c -> c.executors.findAll { it.isBusy() } }.flatten() 

def jobsFound = []
busyExecutors.each { e -> 

    job = e.getCurrentExecutable()

    if ( e.getElapsedTime() > max_run_time_usec ) {
        logger.info("${job.getUrl()} timed out - killing it")
        job.setDescription("Timed out") // <----- trouble!
        e.doStop()
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error

```
hudson.security.AccessDeniedException2: anonymous is missing the Run/Update permission
```

Really don't want to grant anonymous this permission to make this work.

Any ideas on how to get the scripts in init.groovy.d to run with say administrator permissions or as another user that I can then grant the permissions I need?

Answer (score 0):

You can elevate your privileges in the script by adding the following:

```
hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(hudson.security.ACL.SYSTEM)
```

That would allow you to set the build description.